# In which sense are Euler-Lagrange PDE's on fiber bundles quasi-linear?

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, calculus-of-variations, fibre-bundles, jets

In what follows, all manifolds are smooth, Hausdorff, paracompact, connected and oriented, and all maps between any two of them are assumed to be smooth. Let $\pi:E\rightarrow M$ be a fiber bundle over the base manifold $M$, which we assume to have dimension $n$. Given a bundle map $$\mathscr{L}:J^kE\rightarrow\wedge^nT^*M$$ over $M$, where $J^kE$ is (the total space of) the jet bundle of order $k$ of $\pi$ - i.e. $\mathscr{L}$ is a Lagrangian density of order $k$ - we define the *action functional* $S_{\mathscr{L}}:C^\infty_c(M)\times\Gamma(\pi)\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ associated to $L$ (here $C^\infty_c(M)$ is the space of smooth real-valued functions on $M$ with compact support, and $\Gamma(\pi)=\{\phi\in C^\infty(M,E)\ |\ \pi\circ\phi=\text{id}_M\}$ is the space of smooth sections of $\pi$) as $$S_{\mathscr{L}}(f,\phi)=\int_M f(j^k\phi)^*\mathscr{L}\ .$$ The *Euler-Lagrange operator* $E(\mathscr{L})$ associated to $\mathscr{L}$ is the (usually nonlinear) partial differential operator of order $\leq 2k$ defined by the formula $$\int_M E(\mathscr{L})[\phi](\vec{\phi})=\int_M\left.\frac{\partial}{\partial t}\right|_{t=0}f(j^k\phi_t)^*\mathscr{L}\ ,\quad\vec{\phi}\in\Gamma_c(\phi^*VE\rightarrow M)\ ,f|_{\text{supp}\vec{\phi}}\equiv 1\ ,$$ where $\phi_t=\Phi(t,\cdot)$ for any $\Phi\in C^\infty(I\times M,E)$ with $0\in I\subset\mathbb{R}$ an open interval, $\phi_0=\phi$, $\left.\frac{\partial\Phi}{\partial t}\right|_{t=0}=\vec{\phi}$ and $\phi_t\in\Gamma(\pi)$, $\phi_t|_{M\smallsetminus\text{supp}\vec{\phi}}=\phi|_{M\smallsetminus\text{supp}\vec{\phi}}$ for all $t\in I$. The above definition of $E(\mathscr{L})$ can be shown to be independent of the particular choice of $f$ and $\Phi$ under the above conditions. There are other possible ways to define $E(\mathscr{L})$ in the literature, all leading to the same object.

One can see from the above definition that $E(\mathscr{L})[\phi]\in\Gamma(\phi^*V^\circledast E\rightarrow M)$, where $\pi_{V^\circledast E}:V^\circledast E=\pi^*(\wedge^nT^*M)\otimes V^*E\rightarrow E$ is the so-called *twisted dual* of the *vertical bundle* $VE=\ker T\pi\rightarrow E$ of $E$. Since $$\phi^*V^\circledast E=\{(p,q)\in M\times V^\circledast E\ |\ \phi(p)=\pi_{V^\circledast E}(q)\}\subset M\times_M V^\circledast E$$ for all $\phi\in\Gamma(\pi)$, it is clear that $\phi^*V^\circledast E$ is a sub-bundle of $M\times_M V^\circledast E$ over $M$. As such, we can write $$E(\mathscr{L})=\rho(E(\mathscr{L}))\circ j^{2k}\ ,$$ where $$\rho(E(\mathscr{L})):J^{2k}(E)\rightarrow M\times_M V^\circledast E$$ is a bundle map covering $\text{id}_M$ ($M$ is seen above as a fiber bundle over itself with singleton fibers and $\text{id}_M$ as the projection map).

When one writes a local formula for $E(\mathscr{L})[\phi]$ using a local trivialization of $E$ and a local chart for the typical fiber $Q$ of $\pi$, one sees that $E(\mathscr{L})[\phi]$ is always an *affine* function of the highest-order derivatives of $\phi$ if the order of $E(\mathscr{L})$ happens to be nonzero (which we assume to be the case), so it would make sense to say that $E(\mathscr{L})$ is a "quasi-linear" partial differential operator. However, $M\times_M V^\circledast E$ is generally *not* a vector or affine bundle over $M$ (unless $E$ itself is), despite $\phi^*V^\circledast E$ being a (different) vector bundle over $M$ for each $\phi\in\Gamma(\pi)$, so $E(\mathscr{L})$ does not fit into the usual way to globally define quasi-linear partial differential operators (see e.g. the discussion in Section IX.2, pp. 393ff of the book *Exterior Differential Systems* by R.L. Bryant et al.), which requires the target bundle of the operator to be a vector (or at least an affine) bundle.

> **Question:** in which *global* (i.e. coordinate-independent) way one may define quasi-linear partial differential operators in order to encompass Euler-Lagrange operators $E(\mathscr{L})$ acting on smooth sections of general fiber bundles?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Igor gave a coordinate independent definition of quasilinear *equations*  which the Euler-Lagrange equations satisfy. Still missing is a definition of quasilinear differential *operator*, which the Euler-Lagrange operator satisfies.

You already observed that

> $M\times_M V^\circledast E$ is generally *not* a vector or affine bundle over $M$.

hence the definition of quasilinear operator found in Bryant, Chern et. al. on p. 397 (which agrees with the definition found in Krasil'shchik, Lychagin, Vinogradov, [Geometry of jet spaces and nonlinear partial differential equations](http://cds.cern.ch/record/335544) p.160) cannot be applied directly, since they assume vector bundles over $M$. But $V^\circledast E$ is a vector bundle over $E$, and the fix might be to expand the definition of nonlinear DO:

**Definition:** Let $V\to E$ be a vector bundle over $E$ and $\psi:J^k E \to V$ a morphism of fiber bundles *over $E$* (not neccessarily linear, since we don't assume a linear structure on $E\to M$), then the map $\psi \circ j^k$ is called a *nonlinear DO*. Call such an operator *quasilinear* if $\psi$ is affine, when restricted to any fiber of $J^k E \to J^{k-1} E$.

I haven't checked, but suspect that the E-L-operators satisfies this definition of quasilinear DO (with $V=V^\circledast E$). Observe that the zero set of a quasilinear $\psi$ is a quasilinear PDE $\mathcal{E}\subset J^k E$, as in Igors answer. Observe also that a nonlinear DO in the more restrictive sense of: a map of fiber bundles $\rho: J^k E \to W$ over $M$ is a special case of the previous definition by pulling back $W$ to $E$.

Note also that such a generalization of DO is unavoidable in cases like minimal surfaces, where we don't have a fiber bundle structure on the ambient space $E$. (In fact, in the case of jets of submanifolds we probably need to allow vector bundles $V$ over $J^1 E$ instead of over $E$, since the vertical bundle $VE$ doesn't exist and is replaced by a "normal" bundle.)

Comment: I'm not sure if EL operators even fit into your definition of nonlinear DO's: the obvious formula $\psi=\text{pr}_2\circ\rho(E(\mathscr{L}))$, where $$\text{pr}_2:M\times_M V^\circledast E\ni (p,q)\mapsto q\in V^\circledast E\ ,$$ does provide a bundle map *over* $M$, but I don't see how this should yield a bundle map *over* $E$.

Comment: Isn't $M\times_M V^\circledast E$ canonically isomorphic to $V^\circledast E$? I thought it is just the pullback of $\pi\circ \pi_{V^\circledast E}\colon  V^\circledast E \to M$ along the identity $\text{id}_M:M\to M$.

Comment: Yes, it is - I just composed $\rho(E(\mathscr{L}))$ with the canonical isomorphism. However, this is a bundle isomorphism *over* $M$. Even after that it's not clear (at least to me) if $\psi$ as defined above is a bundle map over $E$.

Comment: Certainly $\rho(E(\mathscr{L})): J^{2k}E \to V^\circledast E$ satisfies $\pi_{V^\circledast E} \circ \rho(E(\mathscr{L})) = \pi^{2k}_0$, where $\pi^{2k}_0: J^{2k}E \to E$ is the natural projection. This follows from your $E(\mathscr{L})[\phi]\in\Gamma(\phi^*V^\circledast E\rightarrow M)$ and $E(\mathscr{L})[\phi] = \rho(E(\mathscr{L}))\circ (j^k(\phi))$. (Btw, it is somewhat misleading to write $ \rho(E(\mathscr{L}))\circ j^k$ since those maps are not composable.)

Comment: OK, on second thought I got it, one just has to use local sections to represent points of $J^{2k}E$. Btw, I believe you meant $j^{2k}$ instead of $j^k$ in your last two formulae. Also, regarding your sentence "Btw, it is somewhat misleading to write $\rho(E(\mathscr{L}))\circ j^{2k}$ since those maps are not composable", this composition formula should be (and usually is) understood in the sense of maps between spaces of sections, since it defines a differential operator and such objects are not really bundle maps, except when $k=0$.

Comment: Regarding your last example, it's possible to fit the minimal (Riemannian) immersion problem (or any variational problem for smooth maps, for that matter) into the framework of fiber bundles by looking at the graphs of the immersions as the sections of a trivial (product) bundle.

Comment: Finally, if $\psi:J^{2k}E\rightarrow V$ is a bundle map over $E$, it is also over $M$. Therefore, your definition of nonlinear DO is actually more restrictive than the standard one since the latter also encompasses the case when the target bundle $V$ over $E$ is not a vector bundle over $M$ - see e.g. Definition 1.1, page 39 of the book of J. F. Pommaret, "Systems of Partial Differential Equations and Lie Pseudogroups", Gordon and Breach, 1978. Other authors, like Bryant et al., Vinogradov et al. and Seiler, indeed demand $V$ to be a vector bundle over $M$ but that is not really necessary.

Comment: "In order to define quasilinear DO you probably need some linear structure on V, thats why I've added it to my definition. Obviously if you are just interested in nonlinear DO, this structure is irrelevant, and neither of the definitions seems more general or restrictive." (deleted comment of yours I took the liberty of quoting) I agree, that is just a bit of nitpicking on my behalf... What really matters here is that a vector bundle structure over $E$ factoring through the target bundle structure over $M$ does indeed encompass the case of EL operators.

Comment: Sorry, I erased my remark since I had not thought everything through to the end. What I had in mind is the following: if you have a target bundle $W$ over $M$ and pull it back to become a bundle $V$ over $E$, than you can also lift the original bundle map $\psi: J^k E \to W$ (as bundles over $M$) to become a bundle map $\psi':J^k E \to V$. I have an idea how this works, but I'm not sure about the details.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a " vector bundle structure over $E$ factoring through the target bundle structure over $M$". Certainly the $V^\circledast E$ is not in general the pullback to $E$ of a bundle over $M$.

Comment: What I meant is that the (nonlinear) bundle projection map of $V^\circledast E$ to $M$ factors like $\pi\circ\pi_{V^\circledast E}$, where $\pi_{V^\circledast E}$ is a *vector* bundle projection map to $E$. As for your previous comment, the property you sketched follows from the universal property of pullbacks over $\pi$.

Comment: You're right about the universal property. I now lost track of which things we agree or disagree, but I suspect we mostly agree. Concerning minimal surfaces: the approach you suggest parametrises the surfaces by a fixed manifold. This is possible, but introduces the diffeomorphism group of the parametrising manifold as symmetries of the variational problem. What I had in mind is working directly with jets of submanifolds of $E$ to avoid this.

Comment: At the point we currently stand I believe we essentially agree, yes. Sorry for putting you through all of the above, but I needed to be sure I got all the details of your answer right. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Let $\mathcal{E} \subset J^{2k}E$ be the submanifold (provided that this subset is a submanifold) of all $2k$-jets sitting in the zero-level set of $\rho(E(\mathscr{L}))$, the *PDE submanifold*. This is **Definition 8** in my [[arXiv:1211.1914](https://arxiv.org/abs/1211.1914)]:

> A PDE submanifold $\mathcal{E} \subset J^{l}E$ is called *linear* if $E\to M$ is a vector bundle and $\mathcal{E} \to M$ is a vector sub-bundle of the $J^{l}E \to M$ vector bundle. The PDE system is called *quasilinear* if $\mathcal{E} \to J^{l-1}E$ is an affine sub-bundle of the affine bundle $J^{l}E \to J^{l-1}E$.

In my notation all the bundle projections (as well as their restrictions to sub-bundles) like $E\to M$ and the naturally induced $J^{l}E\to M$ or $J^{l}E\to J^{l-1}E$ are anonymous. One also needs to recall that the projection $J^{l}E \to J^{l-1}E$ is naturally an affine bundle.

That definition is immediately followed by the obvious **Lemma 1**:

> A quasilinear PDE submanifold $\mathcal{E} \subset J^{l}E$ can always be represented as the kernel of a morphism of affine bundles. Namely, there exists a vector bundle $F\to M$ (naturally interpreted also as an affine bundle) and a morphism $f$ such that the following diagram of affine bundle morphisms is fiber-wise exact:
>   $$\require{AMScd}
> \begin{CD}
>   \mathcal{E} @>>> J^{l}E @>\xrightarrow{~0~}>f> F \\
>   @VVV @VVV @VVV \\
>   J^{l-1}E @= J^{l-1}E @>>> M
> \end{CD}$$

Now, I don't think that I had found the same exact definition anywhere else (that's why I don't give any reference), but I think that it's the one that makes the most sense.

Comment: Lemma 1 would be obvious to me if the lower right corner would be $J^{l-1}E$. Could you explain how you get a natural vector bundle structure on $J^l E/\mathcal{E} \to M$?

Comment: It would be completely obvious if all bundles were trivial. Then take the fibers of $F$ to be the same as the fibers of $J^{l}E/\mathcal{E} \to J^{l-1}E$, which are naturally vector spaces (quotients of affine spaces). But if $J^{l}E/\mathcal{E} \to J^{l-1}E$ does not come from the pullback of a bundle over $M$ we can still find a vector bundle summand $F' \to J^{l-1}E$ such that $J^{l}E/\mathcal{E}\oplus F' \to J^{l-1}E$ *is* trivial, and as such comes from the pullback of a trivial bundle $F\to M$, with somewhat larger fibers than naively expected.

Comment: How can the fibers of $F$ (over $M$) be the same as the fibers of $F$ over $J^{l-1}E$? Shouldn't they be bigger by reasons of dimension?

Comment: @MichaelBächtold, well certainly the bases $M$ and $J^{l-1}E$ have very different dimensions (the second much larger than the first), but both bases could certainly support vector bundles with the same *fiber*. Why not? Example: $\mathbb{R} \times M \to M$ vs $\mathbb{R} \times J^{l-1}E \to J^{l-1}E$.

Comment: Yes that's possible in general, but I don't see how it's possible in this case. Take the simplest example of $\mathcal{E} = J^l E$ (the empty equation), then $F=J^{l-1} E$ and your claim is that the fibers of $J^l E \to J^{l-1}E$ are the same as the fibers of $J^{l-1} E \to M$.

Comment: @MichaelBächtold, I think you are reading more into my claim than is really there. In your example, the fibers of $\{0\}\times J^{l}E \to J^{l-1}E$ and $F = \{0\}\times M \to M$ are both the same and 0-dimensional. I only require that the sequence in **Lemma 1** be fiber-wise exact. No requirement is put on the maps between base spaces (lower line of the diagram), other than being fiber-preserving!

Comment: I guess I really don't understand what you are saying then. How can the fibers of $\{0\} \times J^l E \to J^{l-1} E$ be zero dimensional?

Comment: Sorry, that was a typo! The correct formula that I meant is $J^{l}E/\mathcal{E} = \{0\}\times J^{l-1}E \to J^{l-1}E$, which is the same as the pullback of $F = \{0\}\times M \to M$ from $M$ to $J^{l-1}E$.

Comment: Ok, I see now what you had in mind and understand your first comment. Your $F$ was simply not the "obvious" one I expected.

Comment: Thanks Igor! However, as Michael wrote at the beginning of his answer, I was indeed looking for a definition in terms of the operator itself, rather than in terms of the corresponding PDE submanifold (or just PDE, as it's standard in formal PDE literature), as it's more direct. Since I can only concede a correct answer to a single person (I think), I decided to tag his answer as the correct one. Hope you don't mind...