# Hamilton equations for Classical Field Theory

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, calculus-of-variations, hamiltonian-mechanics

This is a second part of my [previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/382463/rigorous-euler-lagrange-equations-for-fields). I'm trying to figure it out by myself how to deduce Hamilton's equations in classical field theory as it is usually obtained in physics books.

**Notation:** If ${\bf{x}} = (x_{1},...,x_{n}) \in \mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $f=f({\bf{x}})$ is real-valued and differentiable, I'll denote:
$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bf{x}} := \bigg{(}\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{1}},...,\frac{\partial f}{\partial x_{n}}\bigg{)} \equiv \nabla f.$$

This notation is useful since, if $f$ is a function of more than one variable, e.g. $f=f(\bf{x},\bf{y},\bf{z})$, then $\partial f/{\partial \bf{x}}$ means the gradient with respect to the $\bf{x}$ variable.

### Legendre Transforms for many variable functions

Here, I'm following [Arnold](https://www.springer.com/gp/book/9781475716931). Let $f: \mathbb{R}^{n}\to \mathbb{R}$ be a twice-differentiable function such that its Hessian $\nabla^{2}f$ is positive-definite (so $f$ is strictly convex). Let $G=G({\bf{p}},{\bf{x}}) := \langle {\bf{p}},{\bf{x}}\rangle - f({\bf{x}})$, where $\langle \cdot, \cdot \rangle$ is the usual inner product on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$. Then, the Legendre transform of $f$ is defined to be the function $g=g({\bf{p}}) := \max_{{\bf{x}}}G({\bf{p}},{\bf{x}})$. Notice that $G$ attains its maximum iff $\frac{\partial G}{\partial \bf{x}} = 0$, so that the vector $\bf{x}$ which maximizes $G$ for a fixed $\bf{p}$ is the solution of:
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{\partial f}{\partial \bf{x}} = \bf{p} \tag{1}\label{1}
\end{eqnarray}

### Classical Field Theory

I know that the more general setting of classical field theory (as well as classical mechanics) is defined in terms of manifolds and tangent bundles, but for our purposes I will work in the usual spacetime $\mathbb{R}^{4}$. In the present context, a field is a function $\phi: \mathbb{R}^{4} \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$. A point ${\bf{x}} = (x_{1},x_{2},x_{3},x_{4}) \in \mathbb{R}^{4}$ is represented by space coordinates $x_{1},x_{2},x_{3}$ and a time coordinate $x_{4} = t$. It is useful to write the equations that follow in Einstein's notation: $x_{\mu}$ denotes any coordinate of ${\bf{x}}$ and $\partial_{\mu}$ denotes the partial derivative with respect to the $\mu$-th entry, $\mu \in \{1,2,3,4\}$.

The action $S = S(\phi)$ is defined by:
\begin{eqnarray}
S({\bf{\phi}}) := \int L(t, \phi(t), \partial_{\mu}\phi)dt \tag{2}\label{2}
\end{eqnarray}
where the Lagrangian is given by an integral:
\begin{eqnarray}
L(t,\phi(t), \partial_{\mu}\phi) := \int \mathscr{L}({\bf{x}}, \phi, \partial_{\mu}\phi)d{\bf{x}} \tag{3}\label{3}
\end{eqnarray}
with $\mathscr{L}$ being the Lagrangian density.

**Question:** Is this a closed form for the Hamiltonian $H$ of such a system, given that $H$ is the Legendre transform of $L$? If there is, how to obtain it?

Let us assume that $L$ and $H$ do not depend explicitly on $t$. As far as I understand, $H$ is the Legendre transform of $L$ with respect to the variable $\dot{\phi} = \partial_{4}\phi$, so we have to perform a change $\dot{{\bf{\phi}}} \leftrightarrow {\bf{p}}$. Thus, it is natural to define $H(\phi, \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial {\bf{x}}}, {\bf{p}}) = \max_{\dot{\phi}}(\langle {\bf{p}}, \dot{\phi}\rangle - L(\phi, \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial {\bf{x}}}, \dot{\phi}))$. Using (\ref{1}), we get:

\begin{eqnarray}
{\bf{p}} = \frac{\partial L}{\partial {\bf{x}}} = \frac{\partial}{\partial {\bf{x}}}\int \mathscr{L}({\bf{x}}, \phi, \partial_{\mu}\phi)d{\bf{x}}  \tag{4}\label{4}
\end{eqnarray}

Here is where things become unclear. Physicists usually define:
\begin{eqnarray}
\pi({\bf{x}}) := \frac{\partial \mathscr{L}({\bf{x}})}{\partial {\bf{x}}} \tag{5}\label{5}
\end{eqnarray}
so that:
\begin{eqnarray}
{\bf{p}} = \int \pi({\bf{x}}) d{\bf{x}} \tag{6}\label{6}
\end{eqnarray}
But the Hamiltonian should become:

\begin{eqnarray}
H = \int \pi({\bf{x}})\dot{\phi}({\bf{x}})d{\bf{x}} - L \tag{7}\label{7}
\end{eqnarray}

But this is **really** strange since the $\dot{\phi}$ seems to be being integrated together with $\pi$, and this is not the case if you put (\ref{6}) into $\langle {\bf{p}}, \dot{\phi}\rangle - L(\phi, \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial {\bf{x}}}, \dot{\phi})$.

So, **what am I doing wrong**?

Comment: Just a general comment, applicable both to this and your previous question. In the study of classical fields, the situation where the numerical value of the action functional $S(\phi)$ and whether it is a true minimum (or even a critical point) at some specific field configuration $\phi$ with respect to a highly technical notion of derivative actually occur very rarely. From personal experience, demands for rigor may really be a manifestation an underlying quest for conceptual clarity, which is inevitably somewhat subjective. ...

Comment: What *can* help with conceptual understanding is working under sufficiently liberal hypotheses so that all formal manipulations that you encounter "just work". A continuous variable should be interpreted as an index? Consider an analogous case where it is an index (e.g., spatial discretization). An integral might not converge? Suppose that all fields have compact support. Is it OK to differentiate $n$ times? Suppose everything is smooth and differentiate as much as you like. These are just some examples.

Comment: @IgorKhavkine thanks! I've had my share of 'hard times' trying to understand some concepts of quantum field theory. In QFT, sometimes is really difficult (if not impossible to these days) to give precise meaning of some objetcs. I was hoping this would be different in the present case, where although a field theory, the 'classical' aspect of it should turn things easier. Actually, I'm convinced after my conversation with Pedro that this is indeed the case. But my previous understanding of the subject, as it is exposed in my post, was not satisfatory.

Comment: My point is just: I agree that being liberal helps a lot understanding the formal manipulations, but it seems that the concepts discussed here are not formal at the end of the day.

Comment: This observation is true for many aspects of classical and quantum fields, more than first meets the eye. However, digging up the "rigor" may be a non-trivial task. To justify the cost, unless you just make it a goal in itself, next time you need a rigorous/highly precise definition or derivation, try to find an important application/situation where it really matters. Exercise: what would it be for your [previous question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/382463)?

Comment: @IgorKhavkine yes, I get your point. To me, its almost the goal itself. I have never studied classical nor quantum field theory before, and sincerely, if I open a physics book I usually don't understand it, most of the time because the lack of rigor. There are a lot of formal manipulations, functions defined only God know where, and so on.

Comment: As for my previous question, I think the appropriate space of fields to be used is a locally convex space. The Euler-Lagrange equations then follow from the variational principle, which states that the first variation (Gatêaux derivative) of the action must be zero. What I don't know: using the space of fields as a locally convex  certainly does not exhaust all possible systems discussed by physicists. As Pedro mentioned below, there are fields which take values on manifolds rather than on vector spaces, for instance. What are the particular fields I'm describing with my approach? Don't know.

Comment: But this certainly describes, say, the Klein-Gordon free field, and this is a toy model in all physics books.

Comment: So the exercise doesn't interest you, fine. If rigor is for you a goal in itself (though I still think that it's lack is not the most common reason that people find physics books confusing), then you might enjoy the reference [_Geometry of Classical Fields_ by Binz, Śniatycki, Fischer (North-Holland, 1988)](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/18523095).

Comment: @IgorKhavkine I'll take a look on the linked reference. Thanks! In due time, I didn't want to be rude (sorry if I sounded). The exercise you proposed is, indeed, useful and I often do that. But, sometimes, it leads me to dangerous paths. E.g. I usually like to think of a $\phi^{4}$ field. But this is a scalar, sufficiently well-behaved field. If I use it as a prototype, and try to generalize the theory, I might end up excluding a bunch of other type of fields in my description. Do you get my point?

Comment: The point is that I don't have a background in field theory. If I did, I could guide myself better.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a fundamental misunderstanding in your translation of Hamilton's formalism to classical field theory, which pertains to the proper identification of dynamical variables.

In classical mechanics, the position variables are dynamical variables, whereas time is the external parameter in terms of which we register the dynamics, i.e. how dynamical variables (position and velocity / momenta, depending on whether you employ the Lagrangian / Hamiltonian formalism) evolve. In classical field theory, position becomes an external parameter *in the same footing as time* and the dynamical variables are the field values $\phi(t,\mathbf{x})$. In other words, classical field theory is about the *space-time evolution* of the field values. That is why in classical field theory the Lagrangian involves field derivatives in time *and* space. **Edit:** actually, as discussed in the comments below and the ensuing [chat discussion](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119253/discussion-between-mathmath-and-pedro-lauridsen-ribeiro), the appearance of spatial derivatives in the Lagrangian is enforced in the case of *relativistic* fields by the presence of time derivatives *and* finite speed of propagation for the Euler-Lagrange equation.

Another consequence of this is that the configuration space of classical field theory becomes *infinite-dimensional* - after all, we are following the time evolution of the field values $\phi(\cdot,\mathbf{x})$ *at each point in space*, thus comprising a continuum of independent dynamical variables, unlike the $n$ (say) Cartesian position variables in classical mechanics - that is, the "coordinate index" $\mathbf{x}$ no longer takes discrete values $1,\ldots,n$ but the whole of $\mathbb{R}^n$. As such, the field momentum $\pi(t,\mathbf{x})$ *at each position* $\mathbf{x}$ and time $t$ should be defined (and actually is, in physics textbooks) as $$\pi(t,\mathbf{x})=\frac{\partial\mathscr{L}(t,\mathbf{x},\phi(t,\mathbf{x}),\partial_\mu\phi(t,\mathbf{x}))}{\partial(\partial_t\phi(t,\mathbf{x}))}\ .$$ In other words, we also have a continuum of independent field momentum variables. This is why the time derivative $\dot{\phi}(t,\mathbf{x})=\partial_t\phi(t,\mathbf{x})$ of $\phi$ appears paired with $\pi(t,\mathbf{x})$ inside a spatial integral in the definition of the Hamiltonian $H$ - this is just the appropriate choice of (infinite-dimensional) scalar product.

Comment: Pedro, thanks for the nice answer. This is something I always get confused about, and I think I'm getting to it. Let me see if I understood it correctly: a field is a (infinite) vector indexed by both ${\bf{x}}$ and $t$. Thus, the space of fields should be the space $\mathcal{F}$ of all functions $\phi: \mathbb{R}^{4} \to \mathbb{R}^{n}$. Then, $L$ and $H$ become functions of $t$, $\phi$ and $\partial_{\mu}\phi$ on that space, i.e. $L: \mathbb{R}\times \mathcal{F}\times \mathcal{F}$ and $L=L(t,\phi,\partial_{\mu}\phi)$. Is this correct?

Comment: Or is it just ${\bf{x}\}$ which index $\phi$ and time is a fixed variable? I think I'm confused...

Comment: Strictly speaking, the space of all functions with a certain regularity (since you want to compute their derivatives) and with sufficient decay towards spatial infinity (since otherwise the spatial integrals may not be defined), but yes. Conversely, classical mechanics can be treated as a field theory living in 0-dimensional space (hence, the dynamical variables depend only on time in this case).

Comment: Right! And time goes as an index as well? Or just ${\bf{x}}$?

Comment: For a fixed time $t$ (say, $t=0$), you may consider given values $\phi(t,\mathbf{x})=\phi_0(\mathbf{x})$ at each $\mathbf{x}$ as "initial values" of these dynamical variables at the instant $t(=0)$, just like the position variables $x_1(0),\ldots,x_n(0)$ at time $t=0$ in classical mechanics.

Comment: Right! I think I'm getting it. Do you know any references on this topic? I really am trying to work it out by myself but it's getting harder. For instance, now I have to consider infinite dimensional Legendre transforms and so on.

Comment: $\mathbf{x}$ is then seen as just an index. However, this is a byproduct of our choice of reference frame. If you are dealing with relativistic fields (i.e. whose Euler-Lagrange equations of motion are wave-like and hence have finite propagation speed), it is conceptually better to think as in Special Relativity and not think of space and time as separate entities.

Comment: I think that a good reference for classical field theory in physicist's language but with reasonable mathematical care can be found in Appendix E of the book *General Relativity* by Robert M. Wald (University of Chicago Press, 1984).

Comment: You may also want to look at the first chapter of the book *Quantum Field Theory* by Lewis H. Ryder (2nd. ed., Cambridge University Press, 1996).

Comment: I'm gonna take a look! Thanks!

Comment: Pedro, one more thing! Writting a field $\phi(x,t) = \phi({\bf{x}})$ is just an alternative way to write $\{\phi_{\bf{x}}\}_{\bf{x}\in \mathbb{R}^{4}}$. Then what does $\partial_{\mu}\phi$ mean?

Comment: $\partial_\mu\phi$ are the space-time derivatives of the field $\phi$ (remark: one usually reserves bold face for spatial variables), that is, partial derivatives with respect to both space and time variables. In the case of relativistic fields, spatial derivatives appear because time derivatives appear, otherwise the theory will be incompatible with finite propagation speed.

Comment: When I posted my question, $\phi: \mathbb{R}^{4}\to\mathbb{R}$ it was obvious to me what $\partial_{\mu}\phi$ was, because $\phi$ was an ordinary function. But now I'm treating it as a vector, and the space-time variables are indices rather than varibales, right? What does it mean the derivative with respect to an index?

Comment: Oh, I think I get it. Each sequence is itself a function, so $\partial_{\mu}\phi$ is the sequence associated to the derivative of that function! Is it right?

Comment: Indexes can always be seen as variables. For instance, $\mathbb{R}^n$ can be seen as the space of all maps from the discrete space $\{1,\ldots,n\}$ (the space of index values) to $\mathbb{R}$. The same is true of fields, but then the domain is now a continuum. So yes, $\partial_\mu\phi(t,\mathbf{x})$ is just the value of $\partial_\mu\phi$ at the spatial position $\mathbb{x}$ and time $t$.

Comment: Perfect! Your comments were REALLY helpful! Thank you so much!

Comment: Pedro, I've been studying my notes and your comments and I believe I it got clear to me. Just one more clarification: as I understood it, besides the certain regularity and smoothness of the field space, I suppose we should consider it as a normed space (probably an inner product space), right? My question is because, if I understood it correctly, the derivative of the expression for $\pi$ in your post should be a Fréchet derivative, right? This is what Marsden et. al. discuss in their book manifolds, tensor analysis and applications

Comment: Not necessarily. If you are only interested in smooth (i.e. infinitely differentiable) field configurations, you no longer have a normable topology in the space thereof. Moreover, if the field values take place in something different than a vector space (e.g. a manifold), the space of field configurations is no longer a vector space but rather an infinite-dimensional manifold. See e.g. https://mathoverflow.net/a/349234/11211 for more details.

Comment: I understand but, althought $\mathscr{L}$ is a function of finitely many variables, some of its entries are fields, so $\mathscr{L}$ would be a map like $\mathscr{L}: \mathbb{R}^{4}\times \mathcal{F}\times \mathcal{F}\to \mathbb{R}$. The partial derivative with respect to, say, the second entry is actually a derivative of a function on the space of fields, no?

Comment: Regarding the derivative used to define field momenta in my answer, you are just taking the usual partial derivative of $\mathscr{L}$ (recall that $\mathscr{L}$ is a function of *finitely many* variables) w.r.t. the variable corresponding to the value of the time derivative of the field and then compose it with the map $(t,\mathbf{x})\mapsto(t,\mathbf{x},\phi(t,\mathbf{x}),\partial_\mu\phi(t,\mathbf{x}))$. This is because $\mathscr{L}(t,\mathbf{x},\phi(t,\mathbf{x}),\partial_\mu\phi(t,\mathbf{x}))$ only depends on the values of $\phi$ and its derivatives at the *single* point $(t,\mathbf{x})$.

Comment: Ah, I think I get it. The Lagrangian $L$ is a function of the fields, but the Lagrangian density is just a function of the fields at a single point. So $\mathscr{L}$ is a map $\mathscr{L}: \mathbb{R}^{4}\times \mathbb{R}^{n}\times \mathbb{R}^{n}\to \mathbb{R}$ (if the fields $\phi$ take values on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$)

Comment: Actually, if $\phi$ takes values in $\mathbb{R}^n$, then $\partial_\mu\phi$ takes values in $\mathbb{R}^{n(n+1)}$. It seems to me from your answer and previous comments that you are dealing with *scalar* fields, i.e. $\phi$ takes values in $\mathbb{R}$, so that $\partial_\mu\phi$ takes values in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$. In the previous case, $\pi$ would have the same number of components than $\phi$.

Comment: In due time: this thread of comments is becoming unreasonably long... Perhaps we should move to chat, should you have any further inquiries on my answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/119253/discussion-between-mathmath-and-pedro-lauridsen-ribeiro).

Comment: @MathMath This has been such a fruitful discussion and your original question is insightful as well. I wish if you could make a little bit time for laymen like us and summarize the main results for us. In particular, if the Hamiltonian density $\mathcal{H} = \mathcal{H}(x)$, then why the Hamiltonian $H = \int d^3\textbf{x} \mathcal{H}(x)$ is not a function of time $t$, doesn't seem clear to me.

Comment: @rainman in the case of Minkowski space-time, if the Lagrangian has no explicit time dependence (i.e. it only depends on time so far as the field $\phi$ itself does) then $H$ is indeed time independent *if* $\phi$ satisfies the Euler-Lagrange equations. This is related to the conservation of the energy-momentum tensor $T_{\mu\nu}$, whose $00$ component is the Hamiltonian density and therefore $H$ is the (conserved) charge associated to the Noether current $T_{0\nu}$.

Comment: @PedroLauridsenRibeiro Thanks so much. I really appreciate it. By any chance, do you have any useful reference in mind where classical mechanics and/or classical field theory formalism is discussed elaborately? I am learning various important tidbits (e.g., your comment) from stack exchange and overflow sites.

Comment: A modern, reasonably pedagogical but mathematically rigorous text on classical field theory is long overdue in the literature. The next best thing, in my opinion, the book by E. Binz, J. Śniatycki and H. Fischer, "Geometry of Classical Fields", that Igor Khavkine has already cited in one of his comments to the OP above - it even discusses the parts on Hamiltonian mechanics that matter to what's being discussed here. However, it's not for the faint of the heart.

Comment: Thank you so much. I really appreciate it.